# Crear pestaña div bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

He estado intentando hacer una tipo pestaña con Bootstrap 5, pero aún no lo logro. ¿Alguien tiene alguna solución? Adjunto imagen de cómo debe quedar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="row justify-content-end">
     <div class="col-10 bg-info">
        One of two columns
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para crear una pestaña en Bootstrap 5, puedes utilizar las clases proporcionadas por el componente "`Navs`" de Bootstrap. Aquí tienes un ejemplo basado en tu código y la descripción de cómo debe verse la pestaña:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Pestaña Bootstrap</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="text-center mt-4">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Pestaña 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pestaña 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active mt-3" id="pestaña1" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="container bg-info p-3">
          Contenido de la Pestaña 1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade mt-3" id="pestaña2" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="container bg-warning p-3">
          Contenido de la Pestaña 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Este código utiliza las clases de Bootstrap para crear una estructura de pestañas. La clase `nav` se utiliza para crear la barra de navegación de las pestañas y la clase `tab-content` para el contenido de las pestañas. Las clases `nav-link`, `nav-item`, `tab-pane`, y `fade` se utilizan para definir los elementos individuales de las pestañas.

El contenido de las pestañas está dentro de contenedores `div` con las clases `container` y otras clases de estilo (por ejemplo, `bg-info` para el fondo azul).